# How to solve Sub-netting Problems

Tags: network-programming

I want help on the topic mentioned above, I am not getting the easier or understandable way of Subnetting an IP with any given subnet mask or getting subnet id of different IP classes.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Is there any code or such that you already have and that you could provide to make your question more precise? If you're mainly concerned with network administration https://serverfault.com might be a better place for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subnet mask is the bit pattern used to separate the network address from the host address in an IP address. Networks perform bit-wise AND operation on IP and Subnet Mask to distinguish these components. This is useful to divide large networks in to small sub nets. Please note than I'm talking about IPv4 particularly here.

Lets say your IP address is 192.168.1.1 and your subnet mask is 255.255.255.0. Following is the bit patterns for these:

```
IP    |1100 0000|1010 1000|0000 0001|0000 0001|
Mask  |1111 1111|1111 1111|1111 1111|0000 0000|
```

Now when you perform the AND operation on these, you will get the first 3 octets of the IP which is considered the Network address. The rest is treated as the host address. You can see for this particular Subnet you can have 255 different hosts.

This is the simplest overview I can give about sub netting. But there are plenty of nice references available in the Internet. Please google for it.